# Правило для текста внутри элемента

Tags: css, css3

Задача такая, есть код:

```
<div>
512
<span>dollars</span>
</div>
```

Нужно применить к 512 text-decoration: line-through, но при этом не затрагивая span.

Перепробовал все похожие на это псевдоклассы, ничего.

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/html/thread1560426.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ кроется [здесь](http://spravka.seodon.ru/css/text-decoration.php):

> Хотя text-decoration и не наследуется, оно распространяет свое действие на текст всех потомков элемента, которые находятся в прямом потоке HTML-страницы. А вот если какие-то потомки являются всплывающими (float), абсолютно позиционированными (position) либо имеют значение свойства display равное inline-table или inline-block, то на них данное свойство не действует.

```css
div {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
div > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
div > span::before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  512<span>dollars</span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6cnuhgmo/

Comment: не то, все становится зачеркнутым

Comment: @Shevsky исправил

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо!

Comment: @Shevsky вы лучше мою ссылку почитайте, там написано почему и как